# Office Add-in Debugging in Chrome

Tags: office-addins

I'm trying to get debugging of Office Add-ins working through VS Code.  I've installed the Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger extension as well as the Debugger for Chrome extension. I have a section in my launch.json file that has a preLaunchTask that uses start:web.

I'm confused about how this process works, currently it opens two chrome windows, which I didn't expect.  It looks like only one of the windows will actually cause VS Code to break on my breakpoints.

I'd like to hard code my document URL while debugging, so I don't have to keep entering it with an inputs promptString.  I guess I'm confused about how these two files work together to start debugging and where do I need to enter the URL to my Excel file in SharePoint.

launch.json

```
 {
  "name": "Office Online (Chrome)",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Web",
  "url": "https://UrlToMyTestExcelDocumentInSharePoint"
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
  "label": "Debug: Web",
  "type": "npm",
  "script": "start:web -- --document https://UrlToMyTestExcelDocumentInSharePoint",
  "presentation": {
    "clear": true,
    "panel": "shared",
    "showReuseMessage": false
  },
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```